# Can I upload and use my current windows 10 pro machine on Google Cloud

Tags: windows, cloud, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Currently I am running windows 10 pro in my laptop. Can i create a drive image of it and upload it to GCP to run it there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score -1):

According to Google's Project Zero team, Google Compute Engine does not support Windows 10 VM, only Windows Server 2016 : https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.fr/2017/09/the-great-dom-fuzz-off-of-2017.html